# ProgressBar output appears to pad console output

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

I'm trying to include Symfony's Console output component into an existing non-Symfony app, and overall it's going pretty well.

The one thing that still seems to be eluding me is that if I use the ProgressBar class, it appears to pad all the output I am sending by the width of the progress bar.

Here's the rough overview of the code (with various unnecessary cruft removed):

```
public function run() {
    $this->logger = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput(fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
    $this->logger->setVerbosity(\Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG);
    $this->progress = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar($this->logger);

    $this->progress->start();
    $this->doStepOne();
    $this->progress->finish();
}

public function doStepOne() {
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 10000000000) {
        $this->info(sprintf('Sweet, done a thing on page #%d', $i));
    }
}

public function info($message) {
    $this->log(sprintf("<info>%s</info>", $message));
}

public function log($message) {
    // This follows advice from http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html indicating that if you output content, you should ->clear() first and ->display() after.
    // If I don't do this, then the progress bar is output on every line, immediately followed by $message
    $this->progress->clear();
    $this->logger->writeln($message);
    $this->progress->advance();
    $this->progress->display();
}
```

So it all seems pretty straightforward. Again, I'm not using this within the Symfony console output, so perhaps that is why, but it seems strange so I thought I'd see if anyone else has come across it. I couldn't find anything using my Google-fu, but perhaps it is weak?

Example (ignore the ^C characters, that's the Ctrl-C to terminate the process):
Also, to clear up any confusion - the first visible line there has *no indentation* that I've added, and the second line has *one space character* of indentation that I've inserted myself, sorry for any confusion.
[image: Example of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also observed this, using Symfony 2.7, using the `ConsoleOutput` stream.  The way I "fixed" it was to manually insert the ANSI delete-to-start sequence into the output. Modifying for your code, that would be:

```
if ($this->logger->isDecorated()) {
    $this->logger->write("\x0D");
}
```

Not pretty.

As of 2.8, this behavior still exists. I'm not sure if it's a bug, or not. It seems like it, though.

Comment: Thanks @bishop, that works for me but does seem like a bit of a bug, or isn't well explained anyway as it seems quite common.

Marking your response as the answer.